# Access property from sub object within an object

Tags: javascript, oop, object

**Problem:** I am really new to object oriented programming. Have been done a lot of reading lately about objects and I am honestly confused about how to access properties of a sub object from within the main object.

If that is not clear I will shown you what I mean:

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rn3btqp0/3/

---

**Example:**

```
// Pseudo code

    obj1 = {
        xy: {
            x: 'foo',
            y: this.x + 'bar'
        }
    }

// Working

obj2 = {
    xy: (function() {
        x = 'foo',
        y = console.log(this.x + 'bar')
    })()
}

// need to access stuff like this

obj1 = {
    xy: {
        x: 'foo',
        y: this.x + 'bar'
    }
    z: xy.y
}
```

---

**Question:** As you can see, Im utterly confused with the proceedings of what I believe is called inheritance (correct me im mistaken). What exactly is a valid way of freely accessing properties of objects within an object?

If anything in my question seems unclear or not well structured, please do let me know so that I can make appropriate adjustments.

Comment: @DavidLi I am aware but honestly I did not really understand it so well which is why I have been hoping to get an example with the xy object there for the sake of simplicity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, none of this is inheritance. This is more rightly called "composition", where one object is composed of other nested objects.

Looking at your code...

***Example 1***

```
// Pseudo code

obj1 = {
    xy: {
        x: 'foo',
        y: this.x + 'bar'
    }
}
```

This example is what people usually want to do, but you simply can't. Using object literal initializers, there's simply no way to refer to the object being created; you need to wait until after it's created. Specifically, `this` has no meaning that will pertain to the object being created.

You need to do this:

```
// Pseudo code

obj1 = {
    xy: {
        x: 'foo'
    }
}
obj1.xy.y = obj1.xy.x + 'bar'
```

You could give `y` some default value if you wish, but none that relies on accessing `obj1` or `obj1.xy`.

---

***Example 2***

```
// Working

obj2 = {
    xy: (function() {
        x = 'foo',
        y = console.log(this.x + 'bar')
    })()
}
```

With this one, it doesn't actually work. The `x =` and and `y =` are creating global variables. There's nothing being added to `obj2.xy`; it is `undefined`.

---

***Example 3***

```
// need to access stuff like this

obj1 = {
    xy: {
        x: 'foo',
        y: this.x + 'bar'
    }
    z: xy.y
}
```

Just like ***Example 1***, this can't be done. The `this.x + 'bar'` has been explained above, but the `z: xy.y` won't work even if `y` did have a useful value. This is because `obj.xy` doesn't yet exist. There's simply no implicit way to access objects being created *while* they're being created.

---

***This works but usually not best***

There are some tricks that can be done, like using anonymous constructors, but the syntax gets a good bit more verbose.

I'll show it here, but I don't think this is often the best way.

```
var obj1 = new function() {
    this.xy = new function() {
        this.x = 'foo',
        this.y = this.x + 'bar'
    }
    this.z = this.xy.y
}
```

Now any object being created is actually using a temporary anonymous function as a constructor. This is because both functions are invoked using `new`. As such, the value of `this` in the functions will be the object being created, so we can refer to it. The functions implicitly return the new object, since that's how JS works when invoking a function using `new`.

---

***Traditional approach***

You're really better of just creating the objects individually. It's a little more verbose, but much clearer.

```
var obj1 = {
    xy: {
        x: 'foo'
    }
}
obj1.xy.y = obj1.xy.x + 'bar'
obj1.z = obj1.xy.y
```

---

***Using named constructors***

If you like the previous one with the functions, then make actual constructor functions and invoke them.

```
function MyObj() {
    this.x = 'foo'
    this.y = this.x + 'bar'
}

function MyOuterObj() {
    this.xy = new MyObj()
    this.z = this.xy.y
}

var obj1 = new MyOuterObj()
```

Comment: I have been using the prototype. It worked well for inheritance. Wow this is a perfect answer. Squint, again thanks a lot and this it a great starting point